# Solving an equation with a combination of logarithmic and exponential forms

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

I've been banging my head against this one for a few evenings in a row and never really getting anywhere:

Express $\ln y = 3 - \frac{9x}{13}$ in the form $y=ab^x$

So far I've mostly tried converting the numbers to natural logarithms, then combining them in various ways. This hasn't really lead me anywhere particularly useful and at this point I'm totally lost.

I'm quite comfortable applying the laws of logarithms, but clearly in this instance something is escaping me, and I'd really appreciate any help.

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.  What goes wrong if you just start from $y=e^{3-9x/13}$?

Comment: $$= e^3 \times \frac{1}{e}^{(9x/13)} = \color{red}{\text{what ?}}$$  Note that $$a^{(b \times c)} = \left[a^b\right]^c.$$

Comment: @lulu thank you for your fast response. I would put in the work I've done so far but quite honestly I'm not sure it's useful, the suggestion you make in your comment has made me think about the problem in a different way and so I imagine I was taking the wrong approach entirely before.

Comment: @user2661923 thank you for your comment. From what you've written I can see an approach to the problem that I hadn't thought of previously. I'll follow that approach and see where it leads

Comment: I've now managed to solve this, thank you both so much for your help. The difference was seeing the form $e^(3-\frac{9x}{13})$ as solvable, at first glance it did not look like something I'd be able to approach

Comment: bear in mind $e^{m + nx} = e^m\cdot e^{nx} = e^m (e^n)^x$.  So That's your answer.  So if you need to get $e^{m+nx}$ into $ab^x$ form let $a = e^m$ and $b = e^n$ and you are done.